# Average rate of change of a function

Tags: derivatives

The average rate of change of the function 
$f (x) = x^4 − 3x^3 + 5x$ between $x = 1$ and $x = 3$ is

Comment: You need to provide your thoughts on the problem. It will help you and the people answering questions more if you explain your thought process.

Answer (score 3):

The average rate of change over the interval is given by $\frac{f(3)-f(1)}{3-1} = \frac{15-3}{2} = 6$